# Почему я не могу вернуть анонимный тип в коллекции?

Tags: c#

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Square<T>(IEnumerable<int> a)
{
    int index_ = 0;
    foreach (var r in a)
    {
        index_++;
        Console.WriteLine(r * r);
        yield return new { num = r * r, index=index_ };//ошибка
    }
}
```

пишет "не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип anonymous type: int num, int index в T"

Почему и как можно это исправить?

Comment: 1. Зачем вам generic тип, если вы возвращаете всегда один и тот же тип? 2. Если нужно возвращать тип из метода, стоит создать его "по-честному", а не анонимным

Comment: @openman2077error Лучше давайте оригинальную сслыку на so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10073319 потому что этих клонов-однодневок развелось очень много.

Comment: ок, понял. было из ближайшей гугл выдачи :)

Comment: Вы сначала сами написали в описании функции, что она возвращает IEnumerable<T>, а потом удивляетесь, что она начинает требовать что-то с этим T, когда вы возвращаете анонимный тип :)

Comment: Как вариант, можно возвращать кортеж.